# No se abre archivo html

Tags: html, github

Subí mi pagina web con html y css a github page pero un .html no lo encuentra y no se porque, y cuando lo subi a neflify si lo abre normalmente,entonce el problema puede ser de github.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En GitHub Pages, es normal que suceda esto si implementaste el sitio hace poco, normalmente hay que esperar unos cuantos minutos para que el sistema se actualice. Ahora bien, puedes configurar un dominio personalizado o usar la URL de formato `https://usuario.github.com/nombre_repositorio/`. Dicho esto, ten en cuenta que el sitio de StackOverflow está diseñado para responder preguntas en forma programática, mas no preguntas genéricas que parecen no cumplir este requisito. Para este tipo de preguntas, está el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).

Comment: Github pages si que funciona, pero el proceso de publicación toma algunos minutos. Dale una mirada a mis ejemplos: https://jachguate.github.io/SOExercises/, por ejemplo: https://jachguate.github.io/SOExercises/598089/acordionhash.html

Comment: muchas graciass